# jQuery - scrolling to the top of an element only if the top is not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Say I have a bunch of boxes that each contain a *"scroll to top"* link at the bottom. Thanks to code posted in various answers I was able to get the scrolling working pretty nicely:

```html
<div class="box" style="height: 500px;">
    <p>some tall box</p>
    <span class="scroll-link">scroll to top of box</span>
</div>
```

```js
$('.scroll-link').on('click', function () {

    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $parent.offset().top
    }, 'slow');

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L1d394ev/5/

However, there's one thing I still need to do, and that's where I'm stuck at: *I only want to scroll if the **top** of the box is not visible*. (*Too high up* to be visible, to be precise.)

I've tried the code posted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6216001/3972493) - as evident in my JSfiddle if you uncomment the `if` - but that seems to disable the scrolling entirely.

What I guess I need to do is check if the top of the element is too high up to be visible, but how to do that, I wouldn't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is the way you calculate the offset:

```
$('.scroll-link').on('click', function () {
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    // Get the offset alone
    var offset = $parent.offset().top;
    // If the offset is less than the scroll position
    if (offset < $(window).scrollTop()) {
        $('html, body').animate({
                      // reuse your 'offset' variable instead of calculating it again
            scrollTop: offset
        }, 'slow');
    }
});
```

#### Updated JS Fiddle Demo

Comment: I could have sworn I'd tried that, but I must have screwed up somewhere. Either way, this is just what I needed - thanks a lot!