# How to scroll in portable native javascript so component is visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The solution: [Scroll if element is not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215779/scroll-if-element-is-not-visible)

shows how to scroll to see a component using jQuery.  Is there a portable way to do that directly, or is it different per browser and therefore jQuery is the only way?

Comment: Do you need to create a smooth scroll animation or is it fine if just jumps to the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the old functions which weren't been deprecated are supported by a very large panel of browsers (at least the browsers used by 99.99% of the internet users). You can check the method scrollTo() and provide x and y coordonates as argument.

Ex : `window.scrollTo(500, 100);`

Here the compatiblity is OK with Firefox, IE, Safari, Chrome and Opera.

Source : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp

Of course, I advise the use of jQuery for these kinds of actions but it can be made without it with not any problem. As @Jackson noticed, speaking about animation, you'll have hard time to animate your scrolling with raw javascript though.